# H2 DB - Need to AUTO_INCREMENT with Composite Key

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have a composite PK and one of the fields is `AUTO_INCREMENT` a `Long`.

I have noticed that doing this way wastes the column, because it really just auto increments and does not take the composite PK into account.

I am looking for this effect:

Example:

```
Section ID
----------
ABC     1
ABC     2
DEF     1
DEF     2
DEF     3
```

However, by using `AUTO_INCREMENT` the result becomes:

```
Section ID
----------
ABC     1
ABC     2
DEF     3
DEF     4
DEF     5
```

The current `CREATE TABLE` statement is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(
    Section varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    ID long AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Section, ID)
);
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your underlying database is MySQL.  That actually doesn't make a difference . . . no database directly supports the functionality you are looking for.

You have two options:

1. Keep the auto-increment key and calculate the sequential value that you want when necessary.  The auto-incremented value has the information you need about ordering within a section.
2. Use a trigger to define the value the way that you want it to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate your primary key as sequential. There isn't any database engine that supports this functionality.